# AngularJS promises - greasemonkey

Tags: angularjs, promise, greasemonkey

Добрый день. Пишу userscript под greasemonkey. Проект собираю `webpack`'ом, сам скрипт на **AngularJS**. Хотя ангуляр первый, использую ES6 синтаксис. Использую `babel`, а так же `whatwg-fetch` и `webpack-async-await`.

На всякий случай конфиг вебпака:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var AsyncAwaitPlugin = require('webpack-async-await');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + '/src',
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', 'whatwg-fetch', __dirname + '/src/app.js'],
    output: {
        filename: "script.js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new AsyncAwaitPlugin({}),
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'ng-annotate!babel-loader?presets[]=env'
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader',
                options: {
                    minimize: false
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

До определенного момента все прекрасно работало. Компоненты, контроллеры, все отлично. Пока не дошел до нативных для ангуляра промисов.

```
class PhotoTemplateService {
    constructor($timeout) {
        "ngInject";
        $timeout(() => {
            alert('hello');
        }, 20);
    }
}
```

Такой код уже ломается.

> TypeError: 'setTimeout' called on an object that does not implement
>   interface Window.

Стек-трейс: https://pastebin.com/QDrZWrzx
Тем не менее, если вызвать setTimeout, все работает.

```
setTimeout(() => alert(1), 100);
```

Так же не работает $q, $http и все, что возвращает промисы. Хотя нативные промисы работают `new Promise`.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема. Буду очень благодарен

Comment: Выпилить вебпак с бабелем и оставить ES2017 как есть.

Comment: А как тогда собирать весь проект?

Comment: Да чем угодно. Хоть просто файлы сконкатенировать через `;`, например. Это ж браузерный скрипт.

Comment: У меня в ангуляровском проекте десятки папок, в них около 100 файлов. Все воедино не собрать по-нормальному. Проблема может быть в сборке? Почему он спотыкается на промисах?